Getting issues while adding baggages via 'micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel'
Background : I am trying to add a few common logging attributes in TraceContext scope as baggages in WebFilter, so that whenever we log any statement, we don`t have to add those common attributes explicitly, these should be added in logs through micrometer-tracing library.
Issue : Adding baggages in context leading to abnormal behavior of Otel-Tracer library. TraceId & baggages are not being cleared from thread for subsequent requests. Whenever a new HttpRequest is received by same thread, old traceId and all old baggages can be seen.
Observation : Same piece of code is working well with micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave
Libraries in use: -
SpringBoot : 3.2.3
spring-webflux : 6.1.4
micrometer-core:1.12.3
micrometer-observation:1.12.3
micrometer-tracing:1.2.3
micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel:1.2.3
Piece of code adding baggages : -
Map<String, String> commonLogs = getCommonLogMap(exchange); commonLogs.forEach(tracer::createBaggageInScope);

Git repo for the sample project : https://github.com/mail2imaran/spring-boot-3-tracing-test/blob/main/src/main/java/some/sample/filter/LogEntryExitFilter.java
Please refer to ReadMe.
I tried with micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave library and it worked well, i want same behavior with micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel as well. I am inclined towards otel because it follows OpenTracing.
